# Exception in R nested loopps

Tags: r

I'm running nested loops in R and keep getting an error. I keep getting an unexpected 'in' error.

```
rowcounter=0
for (item in nrs$hesid){
    rowcounter<-rowcounter+1
    for (name in colnames(all)){
        if (item in name){
            all['all','name']<-nrs[rowcounter,'TPM']
        }
    }
}
```

when I run it

```
rowcounter=0
>for (item in nrs$hesid){
+ rowcounter<-rowcounter+1
+ for (name in colnames(all)){
+ if (item in name){
Error: unexpected 'in' in:
"for (name in colnames(all)){
if (item in"
> all['all','name']<-nrs[rowcounter,'TPM']
Error in x[...] <- m : replacement has length zero
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Comment: `in` and `%in%` are different operators. `in` works in `for` loops, not in `if` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

#### %in% vs in

`%in%` is a vastly underused operator in R that checks for the element `x` in the set (vector) `X`, and outputs a logical result `T` or `F`. By contrast, `for` loops require the `in` keyword to iterate through members of a set, typically expressed as integers in the form `start:finish` although what you have here in `names in colnames(all)`will work.

```
"Hello" %in% c("Hello", "Hi", "Salutations") # TRUE
"Goodbye" %in% c("Hello", "Hi", "Salutations") # FALSE
```

So if all else in your code is correct (no way to know without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)), then this should work:

```
rowcounter=0
for (item in nrs$hesid){
    rowcounter<-rowcounter+1
    for (name in colnames(all)){
        if (item %in% name){
            all['all','name']<-nrs[rowcounter,'TPM']
        }
    }
}
```